# How can i update the name in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let myArray = [
  { age: 21 },
  { name: 'Sara' },
  { test01: 'bla' },
  { test02: 'bla' }
];
```

I have an array of objects, I want to update only name. How can I do that?

This is what I want:

```
let myArray = [
  { test: "Jhon" },
  { name: "Alex" },
  { test01: "Domnic" },
  { test02: "Bravo" }
];
```

Comment: What's the resultant array you're expecting?

Comment: I want let myArray = [
      { test: 'Jhon' },
      { name: 'Alex' },
      { test01: 'Domnic' },
      { test02: 'Bravo' }
    ];

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's going to be better for you if you start with a solution and then ask for specific questions. I'd suggest to try with a .map plus .hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the elements with the `name` parameter only, you can do this:

```js
let myArray = [
  { test: 'Jhon' },
  { name: 'Sara' },
  { test01: 'Domnic' },
  { test02: 'Bravo' }
];
console.log("Before");
console.log(myArray);
myArray = myArray.map(r => {
  if (r.hasOwnProperty("name")) {
    return {name: "Praveen"};
  }
  return r;
});
console.log("After");
console.log(myArray);
```

Depends on what the resultant array you're expecting looks like. For instance, if you want to rename the first user `Jhon` with `Praveen`, you can do so like this.

```js
let myArray = [
  { test: 'Jhon' },
  { name: 'Sara' },
  { test01: 'Domnic' },
  { test02: 'Bravo' }
];
console.log("Before");
console.log(myArray);
myArray[0].test = "Praveen";
console.log("After");
console.log(myArray);
```

If you want every array element's name to be changed without affecting the index, then you can do this:

```js
let myArray = [
  { test: 'Jhon' },
  { name: 'Sara' },
  { test01: 'Domnic' },
  { test02: 'Bravo' }
];
console.log("Before");
console.log(myArray);
myArray[1].name = "Praveen";
console.log("After");
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but op wants to update name not test

Comment: @SagarV Updated. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array index to access the object and assign a new value to the name accordingly.

```js
let myArray = [
      { test: 'Jhon' },
      { name: 'Sara' },
      { test01: 'Domnic' },
      { test02: 'Bravo' }
    ];

myArray[1].name = "Jane";

console.log(myArray);
```

By using myArray[1], you are fetching the second object in the array, which contains the name key with the value Sara.

```
{ name: 'Sara' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `for-of` loop to achieve this. Benefit: This will not dump the previous object by store new value, instead it will only update the name property's value

```
for(let obj of myArray) { 
    if ('name' in obj) { // Another way to check if property exists
        obj.name = 'Rohan';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you

```js
 let myArray = [
    { test: 'Jhon' },
    { name: 'Sara' },
    { test01: 'Domnic' },
    { test02: 'Bravo' }
    ];


   updatedArr= myArray.map(m=>{
      let key=Object.keys(m);
      if(key[0]==="name")
      {return {name: "new Name"}}
      return m
    })
    console.log(updatedArr)
```

Comment: why to use `Object.keys` when you can use `m["name"] = ANY_VALUE` or `m.name = ANY_VALUE`

Comment: i have use `Object.keys` to find Key value i.e. `name`.